# vue | router-view | component created and mounted lifecycle fired twice

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, production

I'm working on a webapp and I have different behevior on local/dev server and production.
ON production, vue-router  load my component but created and mounted is fired twice.
On local and dev server, it is only fired once.

I have tried to debug the production code with fiddler and add console log to check it.
Here is a screenshot
[image: log for lifecycle]

In the picture, we can see that in my component ProductListPage.vue, created and mounted is called twice. But it doesn't call beforeDetroy or detroyed at all.

Here is the App main template

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <router-view />
   <PageLoader />
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the snippet for the router

```
{
   path: 'my_path/(.*)?',
   name: 'ProductListPage',
   component: () => import('@/mypath/ProductListPage.vue'),
   beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      /* fetch data */
      fetchData().finally(next);
   }
}
```

This code for beforeEnter is called on SSR and data are hydrated on CSR

The issue is that 'beforeCreate', 'created' and 'mounted' of the component ProductListPage.vue is called twice but it doesn't call 'beforeDestroy' and 'destroy' at all.

I have this behavior on production code deployed on production only, but on local and demo env I don't have this issue.

is it an issue/bug of vue-router or I have missed something ?

Comment: Does this behavior persists in production if you remove lazy loading for this route?

Comment: I  don't have the hand on removing directly the lazy load on production. I need to follow the deployment process. Removing lazy load will impact other pages performance. But I will try it on our pre-production